# Создание страницы из категории. Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal8

Доделываю сайт на drupal 8.

Есть страница , допустим кровати, на которой есть фильтр по кроватям. Фильтр такой "синие, зеленые, красные, двухярусные".

Финальная цель такая:

Есть пункт меню "кровати" в котором подпункты "кровати, двухярусные".
при переходе на страницу двухярусных должны показаться только двухярусные кровати.

Смотрел в сторону таксономии. На странице двухярусные кровати, на которую перехожу из пункта, таксономии, нечего нет)

Как можно такое вывести?

---

PS
понимаю что описал очень мыльно, мутно.

Задавайте вопросы пожалуйста наводящие, если не понятно.

ГУГЛИЛ, по документации ХОДИЛ. Нечего не понятно

PPS Я начинающий юзверь bitrix, с drupal-ом на ВЫ.

Answer (score 0):

делайте так что каждый товар буде иметь поле Категории типа Taxonomy term, потом выводите страницу с помощью views.
При этом добавив в созданой view CONTEXTUAL FILTERS, это параметры которые с урла будут считываться. Потом просто в меню указиваете ссилки с этими параметрами

Здесь нужно понимать эти инструменты, сейчас не могу описать их но всегда можно доку посмотреть или example